# Toggle between adding/removing class name from an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am working on Toggle between adding and removing class name from an element in Javascript.

Below is the code for that:

```
const yaxis = xyaxis.querySelector('.y-axis');   

yaxis.classList.toggle('y-axis-scroll-bar', .35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight);
```

**Problem Statement:**

In the above code  `yaxis.classList.toggle('y-axis-scroll-bar')` seems to add y-axis-scroll-bar on toggle.

I am wondering what this part `.35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight` of the code is doing above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, check the docs. The second argument to `classList.toggle` [instructs the intepreter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) whether to add the class specified in the first argument, or whether to remove it:

> ```
> toggle( String [, force] )
> ```
>
> When only one argument is present: Toggle the class value; i.e., if the class exists then remove it and return `false`, if not, then add it and return `true`.
>
> When a second argument is present: If the second argument evaluates to `true`, add the specified class value, and if it evaluates to `false`, remove it.

So, in your code, when

```
.35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight
```

evaluates to `true`, the class `y-axis-scroll-bar` gets added to the element, if the class doesn't exist on it already - otherwise, if it evaluates to `false`, the class is removed if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It definitely make sense. I have accepted your answer as well. I am wondering what this line `.35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight` means here ?

Comment: I was having flickering issue on zoom-in/zoom-out or sometimes in the normal mode as well. It was very hard to reproduce so that's why I am not using fiddle in the question. On removing the above line from my code I was able to solve the flickr issue in the chrome.

Comment: Not sure how removing this line solved from flcikering issue in the chrome  `.35 <= yaxis.firstElementChild.offsetHeight / window.innerHeight`